# recursively loop information from each row of a file through a command [bash]

Tags: bash, variables, loops, command

Hello all (newbie question).

I have a file like this:

```
name1 var1 var2 var3 
name2 var1 var2 var3 
name3 var1 var2 var3
```

which looks like this...

```
name1 641 342 613
name2 186 162 903
name3 164 145 113
```

I would like to recursively loop information from each row through a command:

```
./command  --using --name1 and --var1 --var2 --var3 for information from each row
```

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read` in a `while` loop:

```
while read name var1 var2 var3 ; do
    ./command "$name" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
done < file
```

See `help read` for details.